# Loop through files excluding directories

Tags: bash, for

I need my script to do something to every file in the current directory excluding any sub-directories.

For example, in the current path, there are 5 files, but 1 of them is a folder (a sub-directory).
My script should activate a command given as arguments when running said script. I.e. "bash script wc -w" should give the word count of each file in the current directory, but not any of the folders, so that the output never has any of the "/sub/dir: Is a directory" lines.

My current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=`pwd`
for file in $dir/*
do
    $* $file
done
```

I just need to exclude directories for the loop, but I don`t know how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -

for file in "$dir"/*
do
  if [ ! -d "$file" ]; then
      "$@" "$file"
  fi
done
```

Note that it also excludes files that are of type symlink and where the symlink resolves to a file of type directory (which is probably what you want).

Alternative (from comments), check only for files:

```
for file in "$dir"/*
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
      "$@" "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Better to use `if [ -f "$file" ]; then ...`.  Not a directory would return not only regular files but sockets and symlinks too.

Comment: @JRFerguson based on the OP's question I would say that including sockets and pipes would be a really bad idea. As for symlinks, those are implicitly included with `! -d` already.

Comment: I used [ -f $file ] in my final script. Note the lack of quotation marks in the if condition. Almost everywhere I looked had quotation marks around $file, yet I had to delete them in order for my script to work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative to using a for loop if what you need to do is simple (and doesn't involve setting variables in the main shell &c).

You can use `find` with `-exec` and use `-maxdepth 1` to avoid recursing into the subdirectory.

```
[ -n "$1" ] && find "$dir" -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec "$@" "{}" \;
```

The `[ -n "$1" ]` is there to avoid executing all the files in the directory when the script isn't passed any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh, you can use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to restrict wildcard matches by file type. For example, adding `(.)` after the pattern restricts it to regular files.

```
wc -w *(.)
```

To cope with file names beginning with `-` or `.`, use `wc -c -- *(.N)` or `wc -c ./*(.N)`. If you want to include symbolic links to regular files as well, make that `*(-.)`.

The other common shells have no such feature, so you need to use some different mechanism for filtering by file such as [testing file types in a loop](/a/351211) or [`find`](/a/351242/885).

Answer (score 0):

Bash for loop excluding sub-directories ('/') and links (@):

```
for f in `ls|egrep -v '/|@'`; do echo $f; done
```